# Do the FireWire ports on the early 2011 MacBook Pros use 4-pin or 9-pin connectors?

Tags: macbook-pro, firewire

I've ordered a MacBook Pro (early 2011, 13-inch, 2.3 ghz), to replace my aging and breaking-down iMac G5. I'll need to run a FireWire cable from an [audio interface](http://www.motu.com/products/motuaudio/audio-express/features.html) (also on order, that has a 6-pin connector) to the FW 800 port on the MBP.

What size cable should I order? (i.e., 6-pin to 4-pin or 6-pin to 9-pin?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any Mac that has Firewire 800, including the 13-inch MacBook Pro, has the 9-pin connector. You will need a 6-pin to 9-pin cable.