# How do I secure the Firewire cable on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, firewire

Firewire connections can be a little touchy. Since I use my MacBook to record audio - sometimes on location, hooked into an interface or Firewire mixing board - I'm often concerned that the cable will get jostled and disconnect in the middle of a critical operation.

Does anyone know of any method or device that will secure the cable to the [Macbook's Firewire port](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/11914/1758) more effectively?

Low-tech solutions would be welcome. (For example, I use a thick rubber band to do the trick on my portable hard drive, running the cable back through the rubber band and holding it against the top of the drive.) However, I wouldn't be averse to purchasing a small gadget or connector of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very low tech, but some tape is both cheap and effective at holding a cable securely when you start the tape around the cable and then have an inch or two of tape holding the cable securely along the bottom surface of the mac.

Choose one with adhesive that cleans with alcohol and most cables and bottom cases are safe for cleaning any adhesive residue that may remain after your session.

I have also seen people use velcro cable wraps with the hook portion affixed to the cable and a loop pad semi-permanently affixed to the bottom of their MacBook Pro. The loop isn't that disruptive in daily use and you only have the hook portion of the velcro on the cable so it can be tucked away when not in use. This is far superior to tape or rubber bands for a more heavy duty connection under repeated use cycles.

Comment: Unless you are looking for a reason to upgrade to thunderbolt in which case there are _no technical solutions_ and you must instead spend money on the latest and greatest mac with thunderbolt connectors that hold more securely than firewire.

Comment: I have a Mac with Thunderbolt, but I have a lot of money sunk in Firewire audio accessories. Firewire is is! (For now.)

Comment: It may be a good year until a firewire adapter is available for thunderbolt (and it's likely to be pricey as well once it finally ships)

Answer (score 1):

I found that adhesive velcro eventually came adrift due to the heat. i have now come up with a fairly cranky solution which words as long as you intend to use your mac on a flat surface somewhat bigger than  the footprint of the MAC

Get a strip of plastic that just fits under your mac. I guess any size will do but i just use a thin strip. Affix the loop side of sticky velcro onto it just to provide a bit of extra grip. This side will face down toward the surface you rest the mac on - you will not be using the hook side. Attach your firewire lead onto the plastic strip with sugru - or something similar. You need to build it up to the height of the firewire port but it needs to stay slim in order not to disrupt access to the ports either side. Here is the picture not pretty but it works[image: thing to hold firewire cable in place][image: thing to hold firewire cable in place again]
as long as you don't need to keep moving you laptop about

Answer (score 0):

A very flexible FireWire cable will help. You may also want to try using a thunderbolt to FireWire adapter to provide more flex and then taping the FireWire cable into the thunderbolt adapter.

Taping the cable to a table (and not moving the laptop) will also help.

As for the tape, try gaffer's tape. It is frequently used in the live event, broadcast, theater and entertainment industry to secure cables without leaving residue. It is cloth-based and easy to rip.